# VS2003 Build on Command Line Throw Errors

Tags: batch-file, build, msbuild, build-automation, visual-studio-2003

I am trying to do an automated build using the command line for Visual Studio 2003. I have the following codes:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"

Devenv /rebuild debug /project Project1 "C:\Builds\MyApp\Sample.sln"
Devenv /rebuild debug /project Project2 "C:\Builds\MyApp\Sample.sln"
Devenv /rebuild debug /project Project3 "C:\Builds\MyApp\Sample.sln"
```

In my script above, I build each project individually (like I saw in a tutorial on the internet). But each time I try to build, it throws me a lot of errors about the Microsoft Namespaces not being found. Below are sample error messages I get on the build:

- Namespace or type 'Data' for the Imports
  'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data' cannot be found.
- Namespace or type 'Sql' for the Imports
  'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql' cannot be found.
- Namespace or type 'Logging' for the Imports
  'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging' cannot be found.
- Satellite assemblies could not be built because the main project
  output is missing.

I have tried another method to build but this time it's the entire solution but still it gives me the same errors.

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
Devenv C:\Builds\MyApp\Sample.sln /rebuild "Debug"
```

Can somebody please tell me what i'm missing? 
I have over 50 projects in a single solution and it would really help me big time to create an automated build for this.

Thanks a lot! Cheers!

Comment: Can you post one of your .csproj (or .vbproj) file contents?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't do that. The project files consist mostly of class files so we're looking at .CS and some .VB files. Out of all the 50+ project files, I only have 1 Website in there that references to the rest of the Class Libraries I have.

Comment: You can remove the .cs file references.  The "other stuff" is what I'd be looking at.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't "call" the "vsvars32.bat" file.
2. Use the full path for "Devenv.exe" (instead of #1).
3. Optionally: (maybe this is the kicker).....  cd to the directory where the .sln file resides.

   "c:\myfullpath\Devenv.exe" /rebuild debug /project Project1 "C:\Builds\MyApp\Sample.sln"

Try that from the command line and see what happens.

Future Note:

In 2.0, you do NOT use "devenv.exe", you change it to msbuild.exe.  (Just as an FYI).

You can also look up MSBee.  (How to build 1.1 apps with msbuild).

EDIT

All of these lines are working for me.......I don't have VS2003 installed anymore.  But I used VS2010 devenv.exe to run some samples.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"  MySolution.sln /clean
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /build debug  /project MyProject001 MySolution.sln

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /rebuild debug /project MyProject001 MySolution.sln
```

Note, if I switch the /clean with the MySolution.sln (in the first example).....it fails.  So there may be some ordering voodoo.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I already tried calling devenv instead of vsvars32.bat but it only opens up the IDE. The reason I wanted to build using the command line is because I don't want all my project files to load up on the IDE (takes so long because of more than 50 project files). Thanks. :)

Comment: You need to provide some arguments to get the command line to work (and not show the IDE/GUI) .  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I made an EDIT to my original response.

Comment: I currently have this on my batch file but it's saying it's not a recognized command. Any thoughts? "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\IDE" /rebuild debug /project Project1 "C:\Builds\MyApp\Sample.sln"

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\IDE" needs to be "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want but to automate the compilation of my C# projects I use `msbuild`.

For example this is a code I use to build some XNA project games:

### Sample Code:

```
@echo off
set path=%path%;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
Rem In the above line replace "v4.0.30319" with the latest framework version you have
Rem (or include the path to youy inbuilt compiler)

Msbuild "C:\Builds\MyApp\Sample.sln"
```

Now to meet any other requirements you want you can just type `msbuild /?` after you added it to your `path` environemtn variable. The best thing is this will be inbuilt for every windows computor!

Please ask if you want to know anything else, or if you want to do something else.

Comment: I'm not sure, try it out. As far as I know, as long as it is C# and you have installed all the required extensions (for example XNA-game studio) then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
Each of your Projects should have a reference to the "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary" - Files, dlls or whereever these are stored.

Maybe during an open IDE one holds a reference and copies it to the correspodending build folder. (After Build Task). While builing it independly the references could not be found. 
If any copy tasks exist - Check the relative paths. Maybe your depended files targets to a different folder after build compared to build in the IDE.? 
Just another idea..

Comment: I've already tried the first one. On your second idea, my build works fine using the IDE so I guess the paths are correct and files are there. Thank you.